# Can I configure S3 Bucket so that all files uploaded to it so all pages are visible to everyone by default

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Can I configure S3 Bucket so that all files uploaded to it so all pages are visible to everyone by default ?

When I converted an existing bucket to a website I found that none of the pages were viewable unless I gave **Everyone** permission to each file which is a pain, is there a way to default to giving full read permissions on all files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely you can. This is a common use-case for sites that store some (or all) of their static media in S3/CloudFront. Just set up an S3 bucket policy at the root level of the bucket.

Here is a sample policy that allows * (anyone) to GetObject from the bucket you define in your `examplebucket`:

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"AddPerm",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can i do this from the Web UI ?

Comment: Absolutely. Open S3 in console, select your bucket, click "Properties". Under "Security", click edit "Bucket Policy"

Comment: thanks that seems to have worked - just modified the examplebucket part, bit weird there is no gui for the bucket policy options, after all I had already added read permissions to everyone at the bucket level but that made no difference.

Comment: Glad this is working for you, @PaulTaylor - there's also a really helpful policy generator here for all sorts of AWS policies [S3, IAM, etc.]: http://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html